# Why hive count distinct is faster than count group by in my test, what's the difference actually

Tags: hive, hiveql

count distinct

```sql
SELECT country_en           AS country,
day,
       count(1)             AS expo_cnt,
       count(DISTINCT imei) AS expo_users
FROM (
         SELECT cm, app_version_code, event_id, imei, day
         FROM exostsdk
         WHERE day >= '2019-12-01'
           AND day <= '2020-02-23'
           AND event_id = '00***|0*0'
           AND cm IN ('ID', 'IN')
     ) a
         JOIN
     (
         SELECT country_en, version, countrycode
         FROM country
         GROUP BY country_en, version, countrycode
     ) c ON a.cm = c.countrycode AND a.app_version_code = c.version
GROUP BY country_en, day;
```

count group by

```sql
SELECT country_en           AS country,
       day,
       sum(part_pv) AS expo_cnt,
       count(1)     AS expo_users
FROM (
         SELECT cm, app_version_code, event_id, imei, day, count(1) AS part_pv
         FROM (
                  SELECT cm, app_version_code, event_id, imei, day
                  FROM exostsdk
                  WHERE day >= '2019-12-01'
                    AND day <= '2020-02-23'
                    AND event_id = '00***|0*0'
                    AND cm IN ('ID', 'IN')
              ) a
         GROUP BY cm, app_version_code, event_id, imei, day
     ) b
         JOIN
     (
         SELECT country_en, version, countrycode
         FROM country
         GROUP BY country_en, version, countrycode
     ) c ON b.cm = c.countrycode AND b.app_version_code = c.version
GROUP BY country_en, day;
```

in the case, distinct takes 14min to fininsh the job while group by takes 19min. it shows different results than any scene in many blogs I have seen. i'll appreciate it if u can do me a favor!

Comment: Compare both query plans and you will know. Also you are using different columns in counts, the data size may be different and it takes different time to copy intermediate results.

Comment: @leftjoin i think i count the same thing in fact. i've seen the explain plan, it seems the `group by` has one more mr task than `distinct`, and the magnitude of the input data is about 40 billion. maybe the reason why `distinct` is faster is that the extra task will take longer?

Comment: Yes, second query contains additional aggregation step in subquery b